# Flex Form created dynamically only recognizes last added CheckBox as a Checkbox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, checkbox

I have a problem that has been driving me nuts. I create a Form dynamically in Flex using the following code:

```
private function init():void {
            //Dynamically create form based on profiles
            for each(var role:AclRoleDTO in _profiles) { 
                //Create form item
                var fi:FormItem = new FormItem();
                fi.label = role.name;

                //Create checkbox
                var cbx:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
                cbx.id = "role_"+role.id.toString();
                cbx.label = role.description;
                cbx.width = 250;
                cbx.selected = true;

                //Add Checkbox for form item
                fi.addChild(cbx);
                profileForm.addChild(fi);
            }

            //Add save button
            var fib:FormItem = new FormItem();
            var btn:Button  = new Button();
            btn.name    = "Save";
            btn.label   = "Save";
            btn.id      = "saveButton";

            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSubmitClicked);

            fib.addChild(btn);

            profileForm.addChild(fib);
        }
```

This works fine and creates a Form with FormItems that include CheckBoxes based on the available profiles + a save button to save these profiles.

However, when a user clicks on the save button to save the profiles, I use the following method to retrieve the selected boxes but the function only recognizes the last added CheckBoxes as a CheckBox...

```
private function onSubmitClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var formElements:Array = profileForm.getChildren();
            var roleIds:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var i:int = 0;
            var j:int = 0;

            //Parse the entire form
            for (i; i < formElements.length; i++) {

                if (formElements[i] is FormItem) {
                    var formItem:FormItem = formElements[i];
                    var itemElements:Array = formItem.getChildren();

                    for (j;j<itemElements.length;j++) {

                        //If form item is a checkbox, check if the box is checked!
                        if (itemElements[j] is CheckBox) {
                            var tmpBox:CheckBox = itemElements[j];

                            if (tmpBox.selected) {
                                //random stuff
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Send event with roleIds!
            //More random stuff

        }
```

I have tried all sorts of things to make sure that the loop works properly and it does: it loops through the proper amount of FormItem elements and retrieves the proper amount of childrenElements. It just doesn't recognize any child as a CheckBox other than when looping through the last FormItem that was added. If I use flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(itemElements[j]) to find out what the other FormItem children are it returns an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code for your problem:

```
        private function onSubmitClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var selectedRoles:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            var formItems:Array = rolesForm.getChildren();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < formItems.length; i++)
            {
                var formItem:FormItem = formItems[i];
                var formItemElements:Array = formItem.getChildren();
                for each (var control:UIComponent in formItemElements)
                {
                    if (control is CheckBox)
                    {
                        var tempBox:CheckBox = control as CheckBox;

                        if(tempBox.selected)
                            selectedRoles.addItem(tempBox);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently this did the trick though I don't really understand  why I had to go though items as UIComponent for it to work.

Comment: This is approach if use MX Form. RIAStar example is for Spark.
I would suggest to read Bill White's article Core Flex 4 Elements vs Children. http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=296

The UIComponent class is the base class for all Flex visual components, so you cast formItemElement as UIComponent.

Comment: @Deratrius The only difference between this code and yours (as far as I can tell), is the `j` variable. You have a double loop and never set `j` back to `0` in the outer loop. FinFlex uses a `for each` loop, which resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes it looks like so. How the hell I didn't notice that  =)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one, feeling pretty stupid right now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really fix the problem now, but why don't you simply reference the CheckBox in an array? This would be a fast and easy workaround. You would also benefit from a flat hierarchy, making the access easier (and faster, which won't matter in most scenarios).

Comment: Yeah that's not a bad idea and I guess I could have accessed each CheckBox directly. FinFlex's answer fixed my issue though so I won't need to try this. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Flex4 / Spark: the reason is you are using the raw 'children' of the component instead of the 'elements'. With containers in the Spark architecture you should always work with elements (using methods like `numElements` or `getElementAt()` instead of `getChildren()` or `addChild()`). The 'children' methods are only used internally by the Spark components; you should never ever use them to add elements to a container.

So your problem will be fixed if you replace every occurrence of `addChild()` with `addElement()`. And the `onSubmitClicked()` method may look something like this:

```
    for (var i:int = 0; i < profileForm.numElements; i++) {
        var formItem:FormItem = profileForm.getElementAt(i) as FormItem;
        if (formItem) {
            var cb:CheckBox = formItem.getElementAt(0) as CheckBox;
            trace(cb); //null if it's not a CheckBox
        }
    }
```

That being said, I see no reason why you would want to create this form dynamically. If what you need is a list of CheckBoxes, then create a `List` with a custom `ItemRenderer` that has a `CheckBox` and set `_profiles` as its `dataProvider`.

Comment: Thanks, tried your code but it didn't work. To answer your question of why I didn't use ItemRenderers I guess I don't have a valid reason other than I didn't think about it and I am used to HTML forms for which I would also just loop through items and add a checkbox for each of them.